# proof of McMillan Theory using probability

Tags: combinatorics

let $C =\{c_1,...,c_n\}$ be a prefix-free code and let $l_i =\vert c_i\vert ,L = max\vert c_i\vert$, consider $X$, a random binary string of length $L$,

let $E_i$ be the event that the codeword $c_i$ is a prefix of $X$, what is the value of $\mathbb P(E_i)$, the probability that $E_i$ occurs, use this to provide an alternative proof of McMillans Theorem.

I can calculate $\mathbb P(E_i) = 2^{-l_i}$ for $c_i$ with $l_i<L$, but its all a little messy and unclear how to do this is a clean structured way

Comment: You should remind us what McMillan's theorem is, and what the usual proof is; you should correct the spelling mistake in your title.

Comment: You can get the proper font for $\max$ using `\max`. (For operators that don't have a command of their own, you can use `\operatorname{name}`.)